# writing a python script to create an EC2 instance and need suggestions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I think there is something wrong with this code as it isn't launching new EC2 instances. I am using `describe instances` for the command:

```py
import boto3

def main():
    client = boto3.client("ec2")

    response = ec2.describe_images(
        Filters = [{"Name": "ami-test"}]
    )
    images = response["Images"]
    image = images[0]
    image_id = image["ami-0148c8f3i662259a"]
    response = ec2.run_instances(
        ImageId = image_id,
        InstanceType = "t2.micro",
        MaxCount = 1,
        MinCount = 1
    )
    print(response)
```

I want it to launch an EC2 by the name of `ami-test` as well as have the AMI id implement all its settings. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Always provide symptoms, error messages, and actual vs. expected results when asking for help diagnosing coding problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code to `describe_images`. [For correct Syntax](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_images)

```py
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='default', region_name='eu-central-1')

ec2 = session.client('ec2')

response = ec2.describe_images(
    Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'name',
            'Values': ['ami-test']
    }
    ]
)

for each in response['Images']:
    image_id = each['ImageId']

ec2_response = ec2.run_instances(
    ImageId=image_id,
    InstanceType="t2.micro",
    MaxCount=1,
    MinCount=1,
    TagSpecifications=[
        {
            'ResourceType': 'instance',
            'Tags': [
                {
                    'Key': 'Name',
                    'Value': 'ami-test'
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            'ResourceType': 'volume',
            'Tags': [
                {
                    'Key': 'Name',
                    'Value': 'ami-test'
                },
            ]
        },
    ]
)

print(ec2_response)
```

Comment: OP is not setting a name tag on the instance.

Comment: so originally the docs said ```client.describe_images``` and ```client.run_instances``` but i changed it to ```ec2.run_instances``` and ```ec2.describe_images``` was this correct?

Comment: first you want to fetch the image id right. So you have to call `describe_image` first and then `run_instances`.

Comment: Im getting an error for line 15, name response not defined.

Comment: for me its working fine. let me update the full code for you with tags also. give me 5 mins

Comment: I have update the code. You can add as many as tags using `TagSpecifications`. Link I already provided you. Let me know if you  face any issue.

Comment: @notaproatbash if it works for you then don't forget to accept my answer. :)

Comment: im getting an error but its probably just on my side, my describe images name filter does not accept my ami name. any ideas on how i can fix this? ```botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the DescribeImages operation:```

Comment: paste here what/how  you are passing Values in describe_images. Make sure its should be within [] because values are list.

Comment: For more info of clients error: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/errors-overview.html#CommonErrors

Comment: it tells me the filter: 'image-name' is invalid, so is this just an error with my AMI?

Comment: If you are there we can move to chat session. Let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218462/discussion-between-notaproatbash-and-saranjeet-singh).